# Nokia Ad Exchange Ad Tag on Windows Phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Trying to use the Ad Tag SDK for Nokia Ad Exchange for a Phonegap based Windows Phone app.

Download the SDK here https://nax.nokia.com/iamp/nokia/publisher/dashboard#ui-tabs-5

You'll see a file called Ad-Tag.html which contains the code for all the platforms. It seems only the iPhone version shows up in Chrome.

So I tried using the Windows Phone snippet and inserting it into my app and running it on the Windows Phone emulator. Nothing happens.

Has anyone got this SDK working or know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the native NAX SDK for Windows Phone 7, and it works with very little configuration. (Ref: http://networkprogramming.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/nax-advertising-wp7-app/) - However, this requires the app to be developed in Silverlight, not HTMl/Phonegap.

In terms of using PhoneGap, I'd recommend looking at the Server API:

https://inneractive.jira.com/wiki/display/DevWiki/Server+API+integration

You could use javascript to dynamically embed an iFrame in your HTML page in the form:

http://m2m1.inner-active.mobi/simpleM2M/requestEnhancedHtmlAd?aid=MyCompany_MyApp&v=Sm2m-2.0.1&ua=Mozilla/5.0%20%28iPad&cip=107.20.248.13

Where parameters aid, ua, and cip would be variable in your case.